# how could I initialize unordered_map< vector<int> >?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, stl, unordered-map

I met a question in my work

There is an `unordered_map` on `vector<int>` in my c++ class
like this `unordered_map < int, vector<int> >`

so how could I initialize the nested container so that when I insert a key to the hash table
and the value(vector) will be ten zero ?

Comment: And what is the key for the map?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry , the key is int

Comment: You want that `map[key]` return a `vector<int>` initialized with 10 0s when nothing else as been inserted for that key, that's it ?

Comment: @Johan yes , so that i can use like this `hash[1][2]++`

Comment: @Shanicky_C will the vector grow pass 10 elements ?

Comment: @Johan no, it is a fixed length

Comment: @Shanicky_C Then use `std::unordered_map<int, std::array<int, 10>>`

Comment: @Johan so how could i write it in my constructor, i try to write `hash(array<int, 10>({0})` but it won't compile, and 10 is a sample, in my class it is 60, so i couldn't write 60 zero in my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list initialization:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> m
  { { 2, std::vector<int>(10, 0) }
  , { 5, std::vector<int>(10, 0) }
  , { 6, std::vector<int>(10, 0) }
  , { 9, std::vector<int>(10, 0) }
  };
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i just to want to initialize so that when a key was inserted to the hash table and the vector would be 10 zero automatically

Comment: @Shanicky_C: Well, you can't ever just "insert a key", so this question doesn't really make sense: you always insert a complete *value*, which is a pair of key and mapped element.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> my_map;

my_map[123] = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
```

Now `my_map` will contain one entry, with the key `123` and data being a vector containing ten entries.

Comment: @Shanicky_C Read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and its [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 2):

Do not allow users to access the map directly, make them go through an accessor so you can ensure the vector gets populated how you want:

```
class FooBar
{
public:
  // access the map
  std::vector<int>& operator[](int n);

private:
  std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
};

std::vector<int>& FooBar::operator[](int n)
{
  auto iter = map.find(n);
  if (iter == map.end()) // index not found, so insert it
    iter = map.emplace(n, std::vector<int>(10, 0)).first;
  return *iter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to what you stated in the comments you need a fixed size array.
Here a small example:

```
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char const *[])
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::array<int, 10>> the_map;

    std::cout << the_map[0][1] << std::endl;
    the_map[0][2]++;
    std::cout << the_map[0][2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
0
1
```

If you want to change the default value you can do something like:

```
struct my_array : public std::array<int, 10> { my_array() { fill(2); }  };

int main(int , char const *[])
{
    std::unordered_map<int, my_array> the_map;

    std::cout << the_map[0][1] << std::endl;
    the_map[0][2]++;
    std::cout << the_map[0][2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

Not my favorite choice, but you can do it this way.

Comment: @Shanicky_C What is "10 two" ?

Comment: {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}